# Assembly MIPS: turning a decimal number to binary by shifting

Tags: assembly, binary, mips

I have troubles figuring out how to keep a remainder of a division made with the "srl" instruction in a register, to print an integer with its binary value.

f.e. if t1 is the number we want to convert, we use the shift right logical with 2 to divide it, inside a loop:

```
loop:
    srl     $t2, $t1, 2    #number/2

    beq $t2, '0', exit     #if the quotient is 0, exit the loop

j loop

exit:
```

how can a remainder be kept after a srl command and then rewind the bits of the remainders to print the binary number?

Comment: Use bitwise `and`. PS: `srl` by `2` is not dividing by `2`, it's dividing by `4`.

Comment: Print how?  Exactly what kind of result do you want?  How does decimal come into this (I thought you already had an integer in a register, not a decimal string)?

Comment: i already have the integer in t1, so i want to print the integer as seen as binary. f.e. if the input is 9, the output should be 1001

Answer (score 0):

You could shift $t1 to the left by 29 (31-2), then shift back to the right. That should leave you with the lowest two bits in the original $t1.

This is of course assuming a 32 bit integer size.

For an example, assume you start with the value 5. 
Then you have 
`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101`

Shifting to the left by 29 yields
`1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

Then, shifting back:
`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`
which is the remainder.